# Updating an AlertDialog's ListView contents while running

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface, dialog

I have an instance of an AlertDialog that I am using as a file selection dialog. It includes a hierarchical browsing function - if a directory is selected from the list, it should show the list of files in that directory. It also includes a 'up level' button, that returns to the previous folder. I need a way to update the contents of the AlertDialog object's built-in ListView while the dialog is displaying without reloading the dialog object from its builder. I am aware that Adapters exist, but I need a way to load data from a defined instance variable, not an external XML resource. I am overriding the onResume method to avoid dialog closure on button press, and this is where I need to run the list update.

This is the code I have now for the selection button's OnClick listener inside the onResume method.

```
alertDialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position >= 0)
                {
                    String[] list = getCurrentFileList();

                    if(list[position].equals(NO_ITEMS_TEXT)){
                        return;
                    }

                    // If the selected file is a directory, recursively update the file list and redisplay.
                    if(getCurrentFileRefList()[position].isDirectory()){
                        src = getCurrentFileRefList()[position];
                        parseFileList();
                        //todo update ListView from loaded file list
                    }else { // If the selected item is a file, give the value to the handler and dismiss the dialog.
                        handler.handleEvent(DialogActionEventHandler.ResultID.SUBMITTED, getCurrentFileRefList()[position]);
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

*The `parseFileList();` method is used to get the current list of files from the selected source file.*

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the issue with a workaround - here's how.
Since the notifyDatasetChanged() method did not push updates to the dialog correctly without creating an entire adapter class for the initial creation stage - something which I considered far too time-consuming and inefficient for my purposes - I worked around the issue by relaunching the dialog every time an update was needed, and tracked the current directory's position in the master tree relative to the source directory by using an ArrayList with a pointer that updated every time the user switched folders. This process also required making the onCreate() method relaunch-aware, and enabling the onResume() method to be called manually. Once these were done, the resultant section of code looked like this:

```
alertDialog.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if(position >= 0)
            {
                String[] list = getCurrentFileList();

                if(list[position].equals(NO_ITEMS_TEXT)){
                    return;
                }

                // If the selected file is a directory, recursively update the file list and redisplay.
                if(getCurrentFileRefList()[position].isDirectory()){
                    src = getCurrentFileRefList()[position];
                    hierarchyID ++;
                    onCreateDialog(null);
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }else { // If the selected item is a file, give the value to the handler and dismiss the dialog.
                    handler.handleEvent(DialogActionEventHandler.ResultID.SUBMITTED, getCurrentFileRefList()[position]);
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

This discards the old dialog, updates the hierarchy tree tracking array and associated pointer, and relaunches the dialog with the new path. It is significantly more complex than I hoped, but it works well. I hope someone finds this useful!

Answer (score 0):

You should notify the UI to update the list by calling notifyDatasetChanged 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()

Once you update the data in the adapter, you must call Adapter.notifyDatasetChanged.

Comment: Since I need to obtain a reference to the ListView's Adapter and cast it to a variant that can use the notifyDatasetChanged method, does this mean that I also need to refit my initial declaration code to use an ArrayAdapter instead of just an array for the value given to the list setup method in the AlertDialog's Builder?

Comment: @MichaelRunzler I suggest to use the following yourDialogInstance.getListView().getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: I would, but calling .getListView().getAdapter() returns an object of type ListAdapter, which does not have the notifyDataSetChanged() method. It seems to be a subclass of BasicAdapter, so I tried casting it to that and calling notifyDataSetChanged() on it, but although it does not throw an error, it does not seem to actually do anything either. It appears that in order to execute that method, I need to know what original adapter was given in order to generate the encapsulated type ListAdapter, and I have not been able to find that as of yet...